# Random sample of points from a rectangular box with a spherical obstacle

Tags: matlab, function, random

The workspace is given as:

```
limits=[-1 4; -1 4; -1 4];
```

And in this workspace, there is a spherical obstacle which is defined as:

```
obstacle.origin_x=1.6;
obstacle.origin_y=0.8;
obstacle.origin_z=0.2;
obstacle.radius_obs=0.2;
save('obstacle.mat', 'obstacle');
```

I would like to create random point in the area of lim. I created random points using the code below:

```
function a=rndmpnt(lim, numofpoints)
x=lim(1,1)+(lim(1,2)-lim(1,1))*rand(1,numofpoint);
y=lim(2,1)+(lim(2,2)-lim(2,1))*rand(1,numofpoint);
z=lim(3,1)+(lim(3,2)-lim(3,1))*rand(1,numofpoint);

a=[x y z];
```

Now I would like to eliminate the points in the area of `limits-obstacle`. how can I do that?

Comment: You mean "in the volume" instead of "in the area", right ?

Comment: yes volume. not area. It is  in 3D space.

Answer (score 0):

You want to reject the points within the obstacle. Naturally, after rejection you will probably end up with fewer points than `numofpoint`. So the process will need to be repeated until enough points are generated. A `while` loop is appropriate here.

Rejection is done by finding ix (indices of acceptable points) and appending only those points to matrix `a`.  The loop repeats until there are enough of those, and returns exactly the number requested.

```
function a = rndmpnt(lim, numofpoints)
a = zeros(3,0);       % begin with empty matrix
while size(a,2) < numofpoint     % not enough points yet
    x=lim(1,1)+(lim(1,2)-lim(1,1))*rand(1,numofpoint);
    y=lim(2,1)+(lim(2,2)-lim(2,1))*rand(1,numofpoint);
    z=lim(3,1)+(lim(3,2)-lim(3,1))*rand(1,numofpoint);
    ix = (x - obstacle.origin_x).^2 + (y - obstacle.origin_y).^2 + (z - obstacle.origin_z).^2 > obstacle.radius_obs^2;
    a = [a, [x(ix); y(ix); z(ix)]];
end
a = a(:, 1:numofpoint);
end
```

You may want to add a safeguard against infinite loop (some limit on the number of cycles) in case the user passes in the values such that there are no acceptable points.